# Assert values from a group are higher than other groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with several metrics like:

```
    category date level type metric
0   c1       d1   l1    t1   0.5
1   c1       d2   l1    t1   0.4
2   c2       d1   l2    t1   0.7
3   c2       d2   l2    t1   0.6
4   c2       d1   l2    t2   0.8
5   c2       d2   l2    t2   0.9
```

The idea is to see assert that the most recent metrics are higher than the older ones, for each category, level, type group.

Example: for group c1, l1, t1 has old metric 0.5 and newer 0.4 there should be a warning message, while for group c2, l2, t2 there is no need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
check_metric = lambda x: x.diff().lt(0).any()

df['warn'] = (df.sort_values('date')  # data have to be sort by date
                .groupby(['category', 'level', 'type'])['metric']  # for each group
                .transform(check_metric))  # check the metric
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  category date level type  metric   warn
0       c1   d1    l1   t1     0.5   True
1       c1   d2    l1   t1     0.4   True
2       c2   d1    l2   t1     0.7   True
3       c2   d2    l2   t1     0.6   True
4       c2   d1    l2   t2     0.8  False
5       c2   d2    l2   t2     0.9  False
```

If you prefer to extract the group, you can use:

```
check_metric = lambda x: x.diff().lt(0).max()

out = (df.sort_values('date')  # data have to be sort by date
         .groupby(['category', 'level', 'type'])['metric']  # for each group
         .agg(check_metric))  # check the metric
```

Output:

```
>>> out
category  level  type
c1        l1     t1       True
c2        l2     t1       True
                 t2      False
Name: metric, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas` library like this :

```
import pandas as pd

# Put your actual data, this is just sample format
data = {
    'category': ['c1', 'c1', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2', 'c2'],
    'date': ['d1', 'd2', 'd1', 'd2', 'd1', 'd2'],
    'level': ['l1', 'l1', 'l2', 'l2', 'l2', 'l2'],
    'type': ['t1', 't1', 't1', 't1', 't2', 't2'],
    'metric': [0.5, 0.4, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert date to datetime format
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Group category, level and type
grouped = df.groupby(['category', 'level', 'type'])

# Iterate through group and sort accordingly
for (category, level, type), group in grouped:
    sorted_group = group.sort_values('date', ascending=False)
    if not sorted_group['metric'].is_monotonic_decreasing:
        print(f"Warning: Discrepancy found in group ({category}, {level}, {type})")
```